# How to convert PPT file to PDF in python Ubuntu?

Tags: python, win32com

i am using python 3.6 and i tried to install win32com.client using `pip install pywin32` but it shows error on importing link

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pywin32

i am using ubuntu.

`pip3 install pywin32`

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pywin32

Comment: You can't install win32 extensions on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use win32com as it's a Windows-only module. Your best bet is to use the Libreoffice API or a web API providing the conversion service.